# Launch Polyfill.io BEFORE Magento 2 scripts

Tags: javascript

I need to use the https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/ library for a Magento 2 project, so I called it in : htdocs/app/design/frontend/my_theme/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

With this code :

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bhttps://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js" src_type="url" />
```

The library is loaded, but it's loaded AFTER Magento scripts and not BEFORE, so it doesn't work.

Comment: Also looking for the correct way to use polyfill.io in Magento 2. Did you figure it out in the end?